# Is there any good font editor?

Tags: software-recommendation, fonts, editor

There is any good font editor for ubuntu? Like high-logic Font editor for win.
I tried Doubletype, but not worked very well, and really outdated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try fontforge. It is available in the standard repository. Though the GUI is somewhat messy, but it's powerful and I've used it to change names of fonts.

Click the button to install:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install fontforge
```

There is another front-end to fontforge. it is mensis. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install mensis
```

Or using this link: [image: Install mensis via software center]

If apt-get says, no such packages, use this command to refresh package database

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See [this excellent FAQ in the fontforge site](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/faq.html#widget-set) at sourceforge.net . And If you like reading good writings and have time to read the history of fontforge, I recommend you to read [this excellent article](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/ff-history.html) too!

Comment: Fontforge can do the job, but not user friendly, with better ui it can be a score! Thx for the answer, it was helpfull.

Comment: @c001os See the Faq link in my answer. I think, your query about better ui has an  answer there already. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thy, but i can hardly say mensis is super user friendly :). But thx.

Answer (score 9):

See also [BirdFont](http://birdfont.org/).  It is available in the Universe repository since Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn).

Install with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install birdfont
```

Newer versions can be installed from an [upstream PPA](https://launchpad.net/~birdfont-team/+archive/ubuntu/birdfont) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:birdfont-team/birdfont
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install birdfont
```

Comment: just tried installing birdfont on Ubuntu 14.04, got error on launching: `birdfont: error while loading shared libraries: libxmlbird.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @xealits Did you try to install `libxmlbird` ?

Comment: yes, I get `E: Unable to locate package libxmlbird`, the ppa is added and I ran `sudo apt-get update`. Maybe it's not available for trusty?

Comment: I checked and the package is actually named `libxmlbird1`.  However it seems available [only since 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxmlbird1), so you'll have to find a way to install `libxmlbird` manually.

Comment: Maybe try to install manually [this deb (if amd64)](https://launchpad.net/~birdfont-team/+archive/ubuntu/birdfont/+files/libxmlbird1_1.2.4-1_amd64.deb) or [this deb (if i386)](https://launchpad.net/~birdfont-team/+archive/ubuntu/birdfont/+files/libxmlbird1_1.2.4-1_i386.deb).  I'm not sure how to install them directly from the PPA, but once downloaded you can install them with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`.  I'm afraid I cannot help you further.